# Git tries to login into other account

Tags: git, authorization, bitbucket

So, there is my account on bitbucket: BitbucketAccountMain.
I created repository not at first time.
And gave access to guy on bitbucket named BitBucketGuy.
And all time git tries to authorize him with my login.

WTF, GUYS ?

Comment: What do you mean by "tries to authorize him with my login"? It tries to login with your account for push/pull actions? Do you mean something different?

Answer (score 1):

His account must be configured as your standard account in your pc, you can change it, here is tutorial, I know it is a git hub page, but the process is the same:

https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/

Answer (score 0):

Did you give the other user a URL like `https://BitbucketAccountMain@bitbucket.org/BitbucketAccountMain/repo.git`? If so, then you're instructing their system to use BitbucketAccountMain as the username.

That other user needs to change the first "BitbucketAccountMain" (the one before the @ symbol) to their own username, like `https://BitbucketGuy@bitbucket.org/BitbucketAccountMain/repo.git`.

Answer (score 0):

Look on you `origin`, this could happens when you clone repo by HTTPS (when you share clone url without changing username).

```
git remote -v
```

it will show you something like

```
origin  https://<someusername>@<url>/<path>.git (fetch)
origin  https://<someusername>@<url>/<path>.git (push)
```

so you need to replace your username on correct

```
git remote remove origin  
git remote add origin https://<yourusername>@<url>/<path>.git
```

to verify:

```
git remote -v
```